# API MANAGER 1.9 query parameters are not accepted in swagger client console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

[image]After deploying a prototype, when trying to invoke the service without query parameters it works , but when i give the query parameter a value it will say resource not found

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
<am:code>403</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type>
<am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
<am:description>No matching resource found in the API for the given     request</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

how can we support that any query parameter to be accepted after the URL

```
  <resource methods="GET"
         uri-template="accounts/{account_id}/asd"
         faultSequence="fault">
```

Comment: Have you configured resource path correctly with correct data types?

Comment: yeah I did, if i didnt it wont work without sending the queryparam

Comment: What is the backend accepts endpoint?

Comment: it is a protyped one , i provided an inline implementation, still failing

Comment: I have editited the description please look at the image

Comment: Have you enabled JWT ?

Comment: Could you resolve this?

Comment: JWT caching is not enabled the  issue is still hapening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you giving the URI pattern in the API Manger you have to give the "?*" character at the end if your URL contain query parameters. Even though swagger able to create the URL with that parameter,the runtime cannot identify it as a query parameter(runtime is based on Apache Synapse). By adding that character you are forcing the Synapse to append the query parameters to the URL.
so your template should be.

`<resource methods="GET"
         uri-template="accounts/{account_id}/asd?*"
         faultSequence="fault">`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled JWT cahing? If you have enabled, there is a known [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3913) in API Manager 1.9.0, which will be fixed in upcoming releases.

Thanks!

Comment: JWT cache has nothing to do with this problem, it is a problem with matching the URI resource ,  have u tried to reproduce the issue ? simple just design the API and add one query parameter , and then prototype it as as inline implementation, and try to invoke the API from the store using a query parameter , please tell me if it worked for u

Comment: Prototype apis work fine. But as mentioned there is a known issue when JWT is enabled.